# Nav bar not working on click

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, css, navigation

I have this website I am working on for a client.
The theme they paid $55 for (which is just not worth $55 imo) was setup to be a single page website.  However the clients wanted a few other things like woocomerce and a custom social contest application built into the website.
When I am off of the main homepage, the nav buttons do not work at all.  I have gone through all of the CSS to make sure nothing was interfering and I could not find any issues, with the exception of pointer-events being set to none, I changed it to auto, but it made no difference.
Here is the page so you all can check it out http://  www.meatfella.  com/contest-page/
I'm not sure where else to look, except maybe to start digging through JS, to find it.
Either a solution or a workaround would be great.

the site is built on wordpress, and the navbar has no correlation to the cutom menus in appearance, all of those are shut off.  Nav works fine on main page.

Comment: Provide some code maybe?

Comment: Try removing the Shadowbox.init(); from the main page. And tell here what is the result you get.

Comment: I forgot that was there from some testing the other day, but it had no effect on the problem, as it was present before adding that to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of All remember that you are using too many of JS files. And wordpress also has different plugins. You have to use 
          jQuery.noConflict()
The documentation is here.
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

I was not able to find this anywhere in your page. Anything with class "story" was not present.

```
      $(".contentsection.story").offset();
```

This line was causing errors and breaks in js.

You have prevent default being called to those anchors. by this function.

```
      $('#nav a, .arrow a, .anchor, .featurecaption .button').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top - 100
        }, 1000, "easeInOutCirc");
        return false;
      });
```

Now this is being called and hence your anchor tags dont work and scroll. Also the line. $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top is bit of confusing for me. 
Try to jQuery.noConflict() before writing your costume functions.

Comment: Thanks, I will try looking into these more, but JS is not my strong point at all so this won't be simple.
It's not my work I have only been tasked with finishing the site, this being one of the bugs that needs work

Comment: THANK YOU.
I found that line and commented out that line, it works...thank you
It was doing exactly as you stated.